# HowTo use Session in ASP.NET with custom session key parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, session-variables

Is it possible to use ASP.NETs session state with URL like

```
http://myserver/somesite?sessionKey=thekey
```

The problem is, that I have to write a site for a client software which authenticates a user by a request like

```
http://myserver/somesite?user=xyz&passwd=xyz
```

The client expects than to get a session key as result if the authentication was successful.
This session key will then be used as variable in the query as shown above. The client does not support cookies.

How can I implement this behavior by using ASP.NET MVC 4?

P.S.: I know it is absolutly not the way to go but I am not in position to change the client.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want your name attached to code that is so insecure. You have a responsibility as a developer to protect people's account information, especially when you consider the same credentials are often used across several sites.

Comment: The session key in URL is OK. The password is really very weird.

Answer (score 1):

If I do understand you correctly, you could just try it, right?

*(We already met it, and it was a pain for searching engines)*

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="5" cookieless="true" />
```

And I can say it is working
The url generated instead of

"http://server/Product/en-GB/MyEntity"

is now:

"http://server/Product/(S(rxavnpuw05o3fmy3tjnuystr))/en-GB/MyEntity"

Comment: Yes but the client will still try to access "http: // server/Product/en-GB/MyEntity?sessionKey=(S(rxavnpuw05o3fmy3tjnuystr))"

Comment: The style in which is URL generated is out of our hands. It is done before any MVC stuff is put in place. This is ASP.NET cookieless session handling. So, the ASP.NET sessions will always be preset to URL Routing, and evaluated before MVC starts to work

Comment: This is the problem I try to solve. Because the client expects to query every time the same address except the query variables.

Comment: I played with that so much... and it is not possible! Ok, as far as I know. We needed to change it as well, because google was storing the url with session cookie. But we did not succeeded. But still, only my private experience